# Light required at bottom of L-shaped stairs or is on landing only sufficient?

Tags: lighting, stairs

I have a L-shaped stairway with connecting landing going from my ground floor to my to-be-finished basement.  There are 11 risers going down to the landing, then a 90-degree turn to the left, then 5 risers down to the basement floor.

To meet NEC requirements, must I have a light at the *base* of the stairs (in the basement ceiling) controlled by the switch at the top of the stairs, or is one light on the landing (visible from top and bottom of stairs) and controlled by a switch at top and bottom of the stairs sufficient?

NOTE - I don't really want a light at the bottom of the stairs on that circuit.  There is already one there on another hallway circuit that is switched at the bottom of the stairs.

Comment: In my location lights would be required with each section of risers and the lights must be controlled from the top and bottom.

Comment: Even if the section is less than 6 risers?